# When building a Docker container of a webapp, how to import functions from different folders to where the main file (app.py) is located?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

My repo has the following structure (simplified):

```
project
+--x
|  +--y
|     +--z
|        +--app.py
+--util
|  +--database.py
```

In *app.py*, we import a function from *database.py*:

```
from util.database import create_database_connection
```

I want to deploy *app.py* as a webapp using Docker, and created a Dockerfile to do so:

```
FROM felipederodrigues/python37withpyodbc:v1

# Copy required folders and set working directory.
COPY . .
WORKDIR /x/y/z

# Install required packages.
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install gunicorn eventlet==0.30.2
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Set Python path. 
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/home/site/wwwroot/"

# Expose port 8050.
EXPOSE 8050

# Start Flask app.
CMD gunicorn -b :8050 -k eventlet -w 1 app:server
```

Building the image and pushing it to the container registry works as expected, however, the webapp itself does not work because of the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util'
```

Obviously, the app is unable to reach the util folder. Strangely enough, when I move *app.py* to folder *x*, and changed the WORKDIR in the Dockerfile to */x*, the webapp does actually work.

So my question is, how can I make this work using the */x/y/z* folder structure instead of only */x*?

Comment: Did you try adding util itself to python path? then python should pick it up from anywhere. Or you could do /app/x/y/x and add app to python path

Comment: You would say that by setting the pythonpath to /home/site/wwwroot/ that you are essentially looking from the project folder onwards, so that python should see both x and util, am I right? Or since the WORKDIR is /x/y/z, is the wwwroot looking from the y folder onwards?

Comment: I don't understand the point of `/home/site/wwwroot/`. is it the same thing as x/y/z. if so adding that to path would just include z. try `ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/util`.